# Use "secure-http:false" for Composer used by Packagist

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I have Packagist set up to provide a local package system for our project, however the local Gitlab server only runs over `http://`. Where is the composer.json used by Packagist? And is this what I would add?

```
{
    "config": {
        "secure-http": false
    }
}
```

For clarity, the error when I attempt to submit a repo to Packagist is:

```
Uncaught Exception: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Your configuration does not allow connections to http://custom-server/custom/repo.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I run through the Packagist source code and found the file which it tries to load (/usr/share/httpd/.composer/config.json). I assume that directory depends on your web server.

So I created this file:

```
/usr/share/httpd/.composer/config.json
```

with content:

```
{
    "config": {
        "secure-http": false
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation on `why` have you shared this will greatly help, either it from experience or testing it will raise the `quality` of your answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
$/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer config secure-http
```

Set false

```
$/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer config secure-http false
```

Set true

```
$/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer config secure-http true
```

For details see:

```
$composer config -h
```